# Amazon Lambda with Java Resetting Variable

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am creating an Amazon Skill in java using lambda. I am reading a .ics (iCalendar) file and then grabbing the start date, end date, and the summary so the user can ask any date and the program will return the events.

The issue I'm having is with multiple events on the calendar, I want a counter to count how many events. Ex: "There are 5 events on May 2"

Each time I ask Alexa what event is going on, it adds the previous counter to the next. So, if I ask Alexa again, on the same date, it will tell me I have 10 events.... not 5.

The counter is a local variable so should be reset each time the function is called. It does work flawlessly on my computer, it's just the Amazon Web Services not resetting the variable.

```
    public static int countEvents(int month, int day) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < CalendarLookUp.startDay.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (startMonth.get(i).equals(month) && startDay.get(i).equals(day)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through this with a debugger to see why it is counting to 10?

Comment: I don't see a debugger in AWS. It works fine on my computer. It only has a problem when it's on aws

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this does what you think it does:

```
int count = 0;
```

I think *this* does what you expect the initializer above to do:

```
int count;
count = 0;
```

In Lambda, your function may run again and again in the exact same process.  That's part of the speed of Lambda -- it *sometimes* reuses containers and the process inside, and just invokes it again.  You have to design so that you don't depend on this (which you probably already did) as well as so that you aren't thwarted by it if/when it happens.

Another example "gotcha" is when people don't clean up their `/tmp` space.  Some of your old files *might* still be sitting there on the next run.